# RunTime Permissions Marshmallow Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

What will happen if permission is revoked when application is opened? I have already given it a try and found that application's process is suddenly terminated. Everything inside application just simply stopped. And **locally saved Apputil values becomes null when i turned off the permission** when app is opened.If anyone knows the reason please suggest me and how to resolve this issue

```
// I am extending drawer activity to get the saved card number here
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_reward_yourself,
            null, false);
    titleTextView.setText(R.string.reward_yourself_title);
    frameLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
    rewardsSwipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.rewardsSwipeContainer);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridReward);
    tvPointsValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPointsValue);
    tvFirstText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFirstText);
    rewardsSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    rewardsSwipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.black,
            android.R.color.white, android.R.color.darker_gray,
            android.R.color.black);
    initialUiSetUp();
    program = new Program();
     String str= AppUtil.fxs.getCardNumber(); //becomes null when location is off when app is opened

    checkPermission(MyActivity.this);
    mAccInfo = new Account();
    mTask = new GetAccount().execute();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: You have to regularly check the permission whenever you called a method that needs such permission. That way, you can control what to do when the permission is revoked, instead of letting the app terminated.

Comment: @Piyush I attached the part of code.Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You should always check explicitly whether permission is granted by system. For example in my case i am accessing location in my app. All location task will performed by function onLocationPermissionGranted(), So before calling that i will check location permission as below

```
         if (!PermissionRequestManager.checkIfAlreadyhavePermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                PermissionRequestManager.requestPermissionAccessFineLocation(getActivity());
            } else onLocationPermissionGranted();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ebin..I am extending drawer activity here to get the card number from Draweractivity.class but if i turned off location permission it currentActivity.class that Apputil.savecardnumber in drawer activity.class becomes null

Comment: Where Apputil class save card number?

Comment: Its in drawer activity

Answer (score 0):

I hope..I am not late....

The best solution is to use third party libraries...to implement run time permissions in a simplest way...

https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher

I have used the above library. it is best on annotations in java.